# Possessive vs non possesive WH-pronouns

Tags: parts-of-speech, pronouns, pos-tagging, wh-words

I was going through Jurafsky [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/). It says following about pronouns in the context of tag set:

> **Wh-pronouns** (what, who, whom, whoever) are used in certain question forms, or act as complementizers (Frida, who married Diego...).

But there are two categories for Wh-pronouns in [Penn tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html):

- `WP`: Wh-pronoun
- `WP$`: Possissive wh-pronoun

I was guessing which Wh-pronouns are possessive and which are not. I feel only "whose" is possessive and rest all (which, where, who, whom etc) are not possessive. Am I correct with this?

Comment: In your example "Frida, who married Diego...", "who" is not a complementizer. It can't be since it does not introduce a complement clause. Its POS is **pronoun** and its function is **subject** of the relative clause.

Comment: I must admit it's odd to think of _who_ as a complementizer. That would make nonrestrictive relative clauses (and their shrapnel, appositives) into noun complements.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There only 'whose' is possessive:

*The tag for WHOSE is WPRO$.*

*he_PRO asked_VBD hir_PRO ... whos_WPRO$ was_BED the_D child_N within_P
her_PRO$ body_N*

*and_CONJ by_P whoos_WPRO$ commandement_N*

Look up here for more explanations of the Pen tagset:
https://www.ling.upenn.edu/hist-corpora/annotation/index.html